# Referencing and using Java Objects in Kotlin with a context of this

Tags: java, kotlin

how can I reference and use Java Objects in Kotlin when the context is set to 'this'. I am referencing a third party library (mobilething) written in Java. 'this' is the context used in the sample code provided by the third party.

Here is the Java sample of the implementation.

```
import com.mobilething.control_sdk.ManageDevice.ManageDevice;

try {
  ManageDevice device = new ManageDevice(this);
  device.initiateUnlock();
} catch (ManageDeviceException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Here is the attempted implementation in Kotlin

```
class LoginViewModel(private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

private val _loginForm = MutableLiveData<LoginFormState>()
val loginFormState: LiveData<LoginFormState> = _loginForm

private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
val loginResult: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
    val result = loginRepository.login(username, password)

    if (result is Result.Success) {
        _loginResult.value = LoginResult(success = LoggedInUserView(displayName = result.data.displayName))
        val device = ManageDevice(Context)
        try {
            device.initiateUnlock()
        }catch (e: ManageDeviceException){
            //Logger.(Test::Class.java.name).warning(e.message)
        }
    } else {
        _loginResult.value = LoginResult(error = R.string.login_failed)
    }
}
}
```

Errors

```
Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in Kotlin? What type is `this` in the code you posted?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having (e.g. errors)? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The sample `try { }` block you quote is clearly intended to be put inside an object method (which provides the `this`).  Exactly the same applies in Kotlin.  But it's hard to pinpoint what might be confusing you without seeing a full example.

Comment: In _both_ Java and Kotlin, `this` refers to the current instance. So given the same scope/context in Kotlin as you have in Java you can simply use `this` in Kotlin as well. Perhaps you should show the full Java code, too, to let us see what you're trying to translate.

Comment: The error your getting is due to using the class `Context`, rather than an instance of the class. I can't say definitively in your first example because it doesn't include the surrounding method+class, but my guess is that the code was running inside a subclass of `Context` if it was able to use `this` as an argument. In your code you will want to get an instance of `Context` and then pass it to `ManageDevice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to using the class Context, rather than an instance of the class. This worked.

```
class LoginViewModel(private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

private val _loginForm = MutableLiveData<LoginFormState>()
val loginFormState: LiveData<LoginFormState> = _loginForm

private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
val loginResult: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
    val result = loginRepository.login(username, password)

    if (result is Result.Success) {
        _loginResult.value = LoginResult(success = LoggedInUserView(displayName = result.data.displayName))
        val device = ManageDevice(this@LoginViewModel)
        try {
            device.initiateUnlock()

        }catch (e: ManageDeviceException){
            //Logger.(Test::Class.java.name).warning(e.message)
        }
    } else {
        _loginResult.value = LoginResult(error = R.string.login_failed)
    }
}
```